# Can i generate apk through apk

Tags: android

Pl anyone tell me how can i generate own apk within my application

Comment: So your running apk can generate an apk? And then what? I guess you'll want to install it on the running machine?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "generate own apk within my application" in any normal sense. APK files can only be created by the Android build tools, which are designed to run on Linux, OS X, and Windows.